# Is it possible to read a variable from a cfg file?

Tags: python

Is it possible to read paths from an external `cfg` (configuration) file.

I am making an application that opens a file. At present I have to copy and paste the path many times. I would like to write the path in my `cfg` file and call it from my Python program.

This my Python file :

```
import ConfigParser
import os

class Messaging(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
        self.rutaExterna = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "app/properties.cfg")
        self.config.read(['properties.cfg', self.rutaExterna])

    def net(self):
        # with open('/etc/network/interfaces', 'r+') as f:
        direccion = self.config.read('direccion', 'enlace')
        with open('direccion') as f:
            for line in f:
                found_network = line.find('network')
                if found_network != -1:
                    network = line[found_network+len('network:'):]
                    print ('network: '), network
        return network
```

CFG file :

```
[direccion]
enlace = '/etc/network/interfaces', 'r+'
```

I want to store the file path in a variable in my `cfg` file.

Then I can open that file using that variable in my Python file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `self.config.get('direccion','enlace')` instead of `self.config.read('direccion', 'enlace')` and then you can `split()` and `strip()` the strings and pass them as arguments to `open()`:

```
import ConfigParser
import os

class Messaging(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
        self.rutaExterna = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "app/properties.cfg")
        self.config.read(['properties.cfg', self.rutaExterna])

    def net(self):
        direccion = self.config.get('direccion','enlace')
        direccion = map(str.strip,direccion.split(','))
        with open(*direccion) as f:
            for line in f:
                found_network = line.find('network')
                if found_network != -1:
                    network = line[found_network+len('network:'):]
                    print ('network: '), network
        return network

msg = Messaging()
msg.net()
```

also you don't need `'` in your configuration file:

```
[direccion]
enlace = /etc/network/interfaces, r+
```

Tested this and it works.

Answer (score 1):

config parser support reading directories.

some examples:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples

updated CFG file (I've removed the 'r+' from your config file)

CFG file :

```
[direccion]
enlace = '/etc/network/interfaces'
```

updated Python code:

```
try:
    from configparser import ConfigParser  # python ver. < 3.0
except ImportError:
    from ConfigParser import ConfigParser  # ver. > 3.0

# instantiate
config = ConfigParser()
cfg_dir = config.get('direccion', 'enlace')

# Note: sometimes you might want to use os.path.join
cfg_dir = os.path.join(config.get('direccion', 'enlace'))
```